# @keyframes animation not working in firefox 55.03

Tags: css, wordpress, animation, firefox, keyframe

I can't get this working with Firefox. I animated a menu item  anchor that changes background-color, color and border. The animation works fine in MS IE, Chrome, Opera, but not Firefox.

This is my css @keyframes:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes button-flash {
        0% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;}
        40% {background-color:rgba(0,179,179,0.4);color:#000;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:#000;}
        80% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
        100% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
    }

    @keyframes button-flash {
        0% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;}
        40% {background-color:rgba(0,179,179,0.4);color:#000;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:#000;}
        80% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
       100% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
   }
```

This is my css element:

```
    ul#main-menu > li#menu-item-22 > a,
    ul#main-menu > li#menu-item-196 > a{
        color:#fff !important;
        background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9) !important;
        border:1px dotted transparent !important;

    -webkit-animation-name:button-flash;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;

   animation-name:button-flash;
   animation-duration:1.5s;
   animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   }
```

Thank you. Lenny

> > Updated 9/22/17, 0913...

Here is NEW information I'd like to add to my problem description to clarify further...

1. This is a WordPress site with a child theme. My child theme's stylesheet includes *both* the @keyframes code *and* the css code for the elements on the page. In other words, I do not have a separate stylesheet for the animation code.
2. The @keyframes section in my child stylesheet is located immediately above the css code describing the anchor element's animation.

Following lanosmind's answer/reccomendation below, I inserted the `@-moz-keyframes button-flash` section above the `@keyframes button-flash` section so the animation would work on FireFox.  Unfortunately, adding the `@moz-keyframes-button-flash` section did not help.

So now, my revised @keyframes code and css code for this anchor element looks like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes button-flash {
    0% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;}
    40% {background-color:rgba(0,179,179,0.4);color:#000;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:#000;}
    80% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
    100% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
}
@-moz-keyframes button-flash {
    0% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;}
    40% {background-color:rgba(0,179,179,0.4);color:#000;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:#000;}
    80% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
    100% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
}
@keyframes button-flash {
    0% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;}
    40% {background-color:rgba(0,179,179,0.4);color:#000;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:#000;}
    80% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
    100% {background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9);color:#fff;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;border-color:transparent;}
}

ul#main-menu > li#menu-item-22 > a,
ul#main-menu > li#menu-item-196 > a{
    color:#fff !important;
    background-color:rgba(255,85,51,0.9) !important;
    border:1px dotted transparent;
-webkit-animation-name:button-flash;
-webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;

-moz-animation-name:button-flash;
-moz-animation-duration:1.5s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;

animation-name:button-flash;
animation-duration:1.5s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

Can anyone suggest other things I can try to animate this anchor in Firefox?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use @-moz-keyframes as well for cross browser support

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem which presented only in Firefox by: 
(1) deleting the "default" element's background-color and color styles which allowed the same codes in the @-moz-keyframes section to be foremost, and 
(2) moving the entire code section for this  element down lower in the stylesheet.

Lenny